# Problem using localstack to invoke lambda from s3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, localstack

I'm using localstack and trying to get s3 invocations of my lambda working.  I can invoke the lambda from the cli successfully, and s3 seems to be trying, but nothing happens.

I created my lambda with the following command:

```
$ awslocal lambda create-function --function-name mylambda-local --zip-file fileb://mylambda.zip --handler mylambda --runtime go1.x --role somerole
{
    "FunctionName": "mylambda-local",
    "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:mylambda-local",
    "Runtime": "go1.x",
    "Role": "somerole",
    "Handler": "mylambda",
    "CodeSize": 7968172,
    "Description": "",
    "Timeout": 3,
    "LastModified": "2019-08-22T15:16:32.638+0000",
    "CodeSha256": "jyMyhp6H2FryoUGqH1Pyj911KIZO66KLnJs6cWGVb84=",
    "Version": "$LATEST",
    "TracingConfig": {
        "Mode": "PassThrough"
    },
    "RevisionId": "028c8385-ec67-4fe4-b77a-5db05282005a"
}
```

I then invoke my lambda from the cli as follows:

```
$ awslocal lambda invoke --function-name mylambda-local --payload='{}' out --log-type Tail
{
    "StatusCode": 200
}
```

And over in localstack I see this output.  "Lambda starting" and "S3 event received" are my log messages, so I know it's working correctly so far.

```
localstack_1  | 2019-08-22T15:54:56:DEBUG:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_executors: Lambda arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:mylambda-local result / log output:
localstack_1  | null
localstack_1  | >{"level":"info","msg":"Lambda starting","time":"2019-08-22T15:54:56Z"}
localstack_1  | > START RequestId: 6d2cc238-bc8f-1d42-17d7-10a95d4d2109 Version: $LATEST
localstack_1  | > {"level":"info","msg":"S3 event received","time":"2019-08-22T15:54:56Z"}
localstack_1  | > END RequestId: 6d2cc238-bc8f-1d42-17d7-10a95d4d2109
localstack_1  | > REPORT RequestId: 6d2cc238-bc8f-1d42-17d7-10a95d4d2109    Duration: 1.05 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 1536 MB    Max Memory Used: 10 MB
```

Next, I create my bucket, setup an event notification, and push a file.

```
$ awslocal s3 mb s3://test-bucket
$ awslocal s3api put-bucket-notification-configuration --bucket test-bucket --notification-configuration file://notification.json
$ awslocal s3api get-bucket-notification-configuration --bucket test-bucket 
{
    "LambdaFunctionConfigurations": [
        {
            "Id": "bfc3da24-6b82-4f03-b5dc-03e49f4059b6",
            "LambdaFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:mylambda-local",
            "Events": [
                "s3:ObjectCreated:*"
            ],
            "Filter": {}
        }
    ]
}
$ awslocal s3 cp test.txt s3://test-bucket
```

At this point, I see the following over in localstack.  It *looks* like it's trying to invoke my lambda.  All the lambda execution trace looks identical to what happened when I run it directly, but nothing ever seems to actually happen.

```
localstack_1  | 2019-08-22 15:17:33,314:API: 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Aug/2019 15:17:33] "PUT /test-bucket/test.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 -
localstack_1  | 2019-08-22 15:17:33,341:API: 172.18.0.2 - - [22/Aug/2019 15:17:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
localstack_1  | 2019-08-22 15:17:33,348:API: 172.18.0.2 - - [22/Aug/2019 15:17:33] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
localstack_1  | 2019-08-22 15:17:33,354:API: 172.18.0.2 - - [22/Aug/2019 15:17:33] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
localstack_1  | 2019-08-22 15:17:33,361:API: 172.18.0.2 - - [22/Aug/2019 15:17:33] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
localstack_1  | 2019-08-22 15:17:33,368:API: 172.18.0.2 - - [22/Aug/2019 15:17:33] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
localstack_1  | 2019-08-22T15:17:33:DEBUG:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_executors: Running lambda cmd: CONTAINER_ID="$(docker create  -e AWS_LAMBDA_EVENT_BODY="$AWS_LAMBDA_EVENT_BODY" -e HOSTNAME="$HOSTNAME" -e LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME="$LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME" -e AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME="$AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME" -e AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_VERSION="$AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_VERSION" -e AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_INVOKED_ARN="$AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_INVOKED_ARN"  "lambci/lambda:go1.x" "mylambda")";docker cp "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.45928c79/." "$CONTAINER_ID:/var/task"; docker start -a "$CONTAINER_ID";
localstack_1  | 2019-08-22T15:17:33:DEBUG:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_executors: Lambda arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:mylambda-local result / log output:
localstack_1  | {"asynchronous": "True"}
localstack_1  | >Lambda executed asynchronously
```

I was expecting to see the same output in localstack that I saw when I invoked my lambda directly through the cli.  Instead, it looks like the lambda doesn't actually get called.  Localstack just said that mylambda executed async without anything apparently happening.

Can someone please point out what I missed?

Thanks!

Comment: hey, did you get any solution on this?

Comment: Facing same issue, did you find any solution yet ?